# Inner Join across 3 tables with possible empty tables

Tags: mysql

Here I have 3 tables. I want to pull all people that attended either Game A, or Game B or both. Here is a Venn diagram of what I'd like to get:

[image: Inner Join Venn Diagram]

I'd obviously like to have a unique list of people (no duplicates). I started out using two inner joins, but that only gives me the inside circle where all 3 tables intersect (which makes sense).

So, what JOIN or combination should I use to pull this data?

**Person**

- id
- first
- last

**GameA**

- typeid
- checkin_time
- person_id

**GameB**

- typeid
- checkin_time
- person_id

QUERY:

This is what I have tried, which only returns people that have attended BOTH Game A and Game B:

```
 SELECT * FROM Person 
 INNER JOIN GameA ON Person.id = GameA.person_id 
 INNER JOIN GameB ON Person.id = GameB.person_id
```

I am able to get the results desired using this query as well, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person, GameA, GameB
WHERE Person.id = GameA.person_id OR Person.id = GameB.person_id
GROUP BY Person.id
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the table structure and query I've tried.

Comment: Do you need to read any columns from GameA or GameB or just Person given he participate on any games?

Comment: What columns do you want back in your result? You have `SELECT *` in your example query, but the question says you want the people only.

Comment: Just the columns from the Person table, so id, first and last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. One would be to make a `UNION` subquery returning only the `person_id` from both `GameA` and `GameB` then perform an `INNER JOIN` to limit `Person` to those only, or use an IN()` subquery:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Person.*
FROM
  Person
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT person_id FROM GameA
    UNION 
    SELECT person_id FROM GameB
  ) attendees ON Person.id = attendees.person_id
```

Alternatively, an `IN()` subquery:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT Person.*
FROM Person 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT person_id FROM GameA
  UNION
  SELECT person_id FROM GameB
)
```

It might be faster than either of those though, to do the `UNION` on the outside. If you have `FOREIGN KEY` relationships defined where necessary, therefore enforcing indexing, you could do the `INNER JOIN` twice and then `UNION` the results of those:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Person p INNER JOIN GameA ON p.id = GameA.person_id
UNION 
SELECT p.*
FROM Person p INNER JOIN GameB ON p.id = GameB.person_id
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I think UNION is the concept I was missing. Greatly appreciated!